# Why do typed and anonymous key selectors in GroupBy produce different results?

Tags: c#, linq

I don't know why I am getting different results for the two following `GroupBy()` queries. I'd expect them to both return 3 groupings, but the typed key selector `GroupBy()` returns 4.

Given a key class:

```
class Key
{
    public int Day { get; set; }
}
```

When I run:

```
var data = new[]
{
    new { Date = DateTime.Now },
    new { Date = DateTime.Now },
    new { Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) },
    new { Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2) }
};

var groupsByAnonymousKey = data.GroupBy(m => new
{
    m.Date.DayOfYear
});

var groupsByTypedKey = data.GroupBy(m => new Key
{
    Day = m.Date.DayOfYear
});

var anonymousCount = groupsByAnonymousKey.Count(); // 3
var typedCount = groupsByTypedKey.Count();         // 4
```

`anonymousCount` is 3 and `typedCount` is 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because at second variant you group by **class**: `Key`. Class instances not equal each other, even if all their properties are equal, instead of **anonumous** types. So `typedCount` always will be equal `data.Length`. To fix it, you can specify `comparer` at another versions of `GroupBy` operator or override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods of `Key` class, also you can change `Key` class to `struct`.